# Can I use S3 to host images, and use them on my EC2 website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a website, and I realized that it is taking a long time to load the site, it takes around 10 seconds to load the entire page, and I believe this is due to the high resolution and long length images, the question is:

Is it better to upload images to a Bucket on S3, and then use the image object link in my website's  tags? Will this decrease this delay in loading the site?
Well, the images that I currently use on the site, are inside the site folder, this is what may be taking so long, isn't it? I believe that my EC2 is working hard because of these high resolution and long length images

Comment: You could try it and see. Should be simple to do. Alternatively, consider using lower resolution images for displaying on the web page, if that's really the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will certainly reduce the load on your EC2 instance. If you have S3 transfer acceleration enabled it may also serve the images to the browser faster. To really make the images serve to the browser as fast as possible you should place a CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare in front of the S3 bucket.